# Reset session in jsp without invalidating

Tags: java, jsp, session

I want to reset the session in a JSP page without invalidating it.
The reason for this is, the user might have an already opened page using the session and invalidating it would throw a `NullPointerException`. Since a fresh session is already been catched, I don't want to add an additional catch-phrase. The goal is to clean all Attributes.

I am looking for something like:

```java
session = new HttpSession(); //this does obviously not work
```

an alternative would be (?)

```java
while(session.getAttributeNames().hasMoreElements()){
    session.removeAttribute(session.getAttributeNames().nextElement());
}    //cleans session?
```

But I am not sure, if this deletes some necessary session-attributes like login-data.

Is there a nice way to do this?

**Edit:** The best solution would be, each time you open a certain page you create a new session for that window/tab until you close the tab or revisit that page in this tab. This question occurred by the attempt to solve [this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224995/how-to-have-several-sessions-for-same-user)

Comment: But wouldn't killing all values risk access to no-longer-available-items as well? Could you explain under which circumstances you'd need the session "cleaned" instead of renewed?

Comment: @Jan In the session I save some huge amount of datas for controlling saved, hence I would like to completely refresh the session. But in some other tab I might have an open page of an other control-run, which I dont like to crash with an NullPointer. So a new session would be also fine, but if I use invalidate, it just sets the session in the other tab to `null`, which is kind of meh. The no-longer-availability is already catched, hence I dont want to add another cath-phrase.

Comment: okay. Having all this data under multiple session attributes might be difficult - you'll probably end up with the loop you suggested. But how about using **one** session key and store a `Map<String,Object>` for that one key? That way you could `((Map)session.getAttribute("myKey")).clear();`

Comment: This would be a way, but seems a little bit overhead for me, since then I need to add the map in every session-attribute (and change a lot of code right now). I was just hoping, there is a method or way to do this directly with the session (like the first line in the question), in the way to apply a new session-instance without a new request or clean the session.

Comment: So you want to reset all the data in the session in one page, yet still have it there in another?

Comment: @coladict That would be really great, but I don't think that would be possible (would probably tend to behave really strangely). The best solution would be, to create each time you open a certain page a new session for that window/tab until you close the tab or revisit that page in this tab.

Comment: Can't you just make the JSP that doesn't need that data simply ignore it, instead of reading it from the session? I can't even think of any reason why that would be a problem. Simply don't call `session.getAttribute` for the things you want to ignore.

Comment: That's not the issue. It's the mere amount of Attributes saved, which troubles me. Since the session might be active for quite a long time and it saves a lot of data in it, I want to make sure, it cleans from time to time the saved data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there's a nice way to do this. Create a class that wraps the `HttpSession` object and implement a `Map` interface. In the implementation you can manipulate session attributes without invalidation of the session. Similar like the implemented code for [`SessionMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.3.16.3/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/SessionMap.java/) in the Struts2 framework. You can read docs page for [`SessionMap`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/SessionMap.html) here.

> A simple implementation of the `Map` interface to handle a collection of
>   HTTP session attributes. The `entrySet()` method enumerates over all
>   session attributes and creates a `Set` of entries. Note, this will occur
>   lazily - only when the entry set is asked for.

Similar implementation of [SessionMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.2/com/sun/faces/context/SessionMap.java) you can find in JSF. The docs page you can find [here](https://javadocs.com/docs/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.2/com/sun/faces/context/SessionMap.html).

> ```
> public class SessionMap extends
>     java.util.AbstractMap<java.lang.String,V>
> ```
>
> See Also:
>       `javax.faces.context.ExternalContext#getSessionMap()`

If you use any of these frameworks, you can use or override the `clear()` method to get what you want.

Comment: But then I would still have the problem, that I might delete authentication objects. The wrapper would make it easier to handle the cleaning since it keeps the change at one place (+1 for this, will implement something similar), but the problem with proper cleaning still persists. Right now both implementations also just do the same I already thought of, running over all attributes and deleting them. If there would be a way to know the "system" session-attributes, that would help to avoid them while cleaning.

Comment: I have already answered [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16919064/573032) in my answer.

Comment: This should work, I will try to implement it. Thank you for the answer! (You will get the bounty, when I finished implementing or time runs out, whatever the first :-) )

Answer (score 3):

The [HttpSession API](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) clearly does not provide such feature.

The above loop might be written a bit nicer using the Java5 iterator idiom:

```
for (final String an : session.getAttributeNames()) {
    session.removeAttribute(an);
}
```

But that requires the [Enumeration to be iterable](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue107.html).

What I am wondering: You want to clear *all* session data, but still keep the session so that some other control run, which seems to be using the session, does not crash. Does this really work? The second control run will not find any session data, as you have completely cleared out the session.

I believe one of those is true:

1. your session clean-up removes data needed by the second control-run
2. it would be better to invalidate the session and enable the control-run to deal with an invalidated session.

The HttpSession documentation clearly states that any entity using the session must be able to deal with the fact that a session gets lost or never existed in the first place, so point 2 should be implemeneted anyways.

In the sense of extendiblity (what happens if there is data from other processes in your session? Your loop would clear them out as well) I suggest instead of clearing the whole session you keep track of the session values put by your control-run and clear out those explicit values only.

Comment: Fun fact is I tried it first with the for/in statement, but since Enumeration is not iterable per se (they should have added that in Java 8) this way has less code in it and is more readable. Your first point is true, my program can handle this loss. To the second point: What is the advantage of invalidating towards clearing all attributes? It is not the loss of the attributes that bothers me, but the fact that session is null. Is there a way to at least set it to a new instance? About the last statement: this is something I now truly consider (as a list added in sessions).

Comment: On second thought: there is no advantage in invalidating a session, especially - in a more complex project - if you cannot be sure who else has stored data in the session (but that applies to the clearing, too).

I use invalidate only at one point: When the user logs out and I want to make sure nothing authenticated is left. Besides this a general clean-up might throw away data some module may still need.

(But then I do not know about your project - maybe that is not an issue at all.)

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of this trick like we used to set the values in session

```
session.setAttribute( "name", "value");
```

instead of resetting the whole session object,just set some empty values to  session parameters so it will be null and  `session` Object will not throw NullPointerException.

for example

```
session.setAttribute( "name", "");
```

Comment: You mean `session.setAttribute("name", null);` Your code would set the attribute to an empty String. Setting an attribute to `null` pretty much gets you the same output, when you try to get it, as removing it. The only difference I can think of right now is, it will still be saved as empty attribute (e.g. you get it by `session.getAttributeNames()`).